# Using variables for source attachments in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm collaborating on an Android project with several other developers. Our project includes several *Libraries*, and each Library has a *Source attachment*. These source attachments have different paths on each developer's computer.

How can I configure Eclipse (.classpath) to use variables for source attachments instead of full paths?

An example of configuring Java Build Path to solve this problem, or better ways of handling this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want in Eclipse.  At my company, we usually put our source attachments inside the project, and reference them using a workspace-relative path.

For example, the directory structure might look like this:

```
+ Project
  + lib
    - mylib.jar
    - mylib2.jar
  + lib-src
    - mylib-src.jar
    - mylib2-src.jar
```

Then when adding `mylib.jar` to the build path, set the source attachment for the jarfile to `/Project/lib-src/mylib-src.jar`.

Commit the source attachment files and the `.classpath` file to the repository (if you aren't using a code repository yet, get one!), and then all of your developers should have the source attachment available when they update.

**Update**

If you can't put the source files in the same project, you can put the source files in another project in the workspace:

```
+ Project
  + lib
    - mylib.jar
    - mylib2.jar
+ Project-src
  + lib-src
    - mylib-src.jar
    - mylib2-src.jar
```

In this case, you would set the source attachment to `/Project-src/lib-src/mylib-src.jar`

Comment: Thanks for sharing, sounds like a good strategy. Unfortunately, in my particular case, I need to link to an external folder because updates to this jar are managed by a different tool and I don't want to include source jars when I ship my app

Comment: How do you build your distribution for the app?  It seems strange to me that you can't prevent the files in `lib-src` from making it into the distribution.  At any rate, I updated my answer to show how you could also link source from a separate project in the same workspace, might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project, and select `Build Path -> Link Source...`

From that dialog box there is a `Variables...` button that might be exactly what you're looking for. Then when you link source to a library, you can select a subfolder of that variable rather than the complete path.